# Advantages of using non-hash URLs for page sections and how to implement them?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

Lately, I've seen many websites with the URL structure:

```
http://example.com/page/section-1
http://example.com/page/section-2
http://example.com/page/section-3
```

where `/section-1`, `/section-2` and `/section-3` link to `#section-1`, `#section-2` and `#section-3` fragments on `http://example.com/page`

These are basically, links to different sections on the same page.

I'm wondering if this is a good approach for SEO and also easy navigation across the content. But are there any downsides? I hope search engines don't scan these as different pages with duplicate content.

These URLs also seem to update as the user scrolls down the page. I tried searching for help, but couldn't find much. Maybe I'm not searching for the right keywords - heck, I don't even know what this is called!

I'm wondering if this is safe to try for my new website. If yes, how do I implement this?